# how we can implement the An automated process to identify / fetch the unused Global variables

Tags: tibco

how we can implement the An automated process to identify / fetch the unused Global variables from the BW project and those un used global varaibles i need to write in to file

Answer (score 0):

Under TIBCO_HOME/designer/bin folder there is a utility called ValidateProject. This utility can help you find out unused Global Variables. Refer to the documentation at https://docs.tibco.com/pub/designer/5.7.1_january_2011/html/tib_designer_user/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=designer.5.12.htm&single=true to get more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: while trying to open the ValidateProject utility just for few secounds it appears and after that disappeared .  . and those unused global varaibles i wnat in a excel sheet .Help me on this